# How to prevent SQL files opening new instances of SSMS 17.9.1?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

**Synopsis**

This is not a new problem and there are several *solutions* floating around on Internet.

**Problem**

When you double click on a `.sql` file, a new instance of SSMS is opened. I did not have this problem until new SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS 17.9.1) was installed.

**What I tried**

- [This page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/63a603cc-d970-4434-8f80-309dc9ea688e/sql-files-opening-in-new-ssms-instance) lists several solutions suggesting registry changes and file associations, and reinstalling SSMS. None worked.
- [This one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ac2f39c5-66e5-495c-b7a6-47e743853baf/opening-sql-files-opens-new-instance-of-sql-management-studio) has almost the same as the previous link. *(SO is so much better than those forums.)*
- Registry changes are shown [here](http://pietervanhove.azurewebsites.net/?p=2321) with excellent screenshots. I added `"%1"` but that did not make any difference.
- The suggestion [mentioned on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7123365/1050256) did not work either.
- On [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/229055/32970), it is mostly talking about raised permissions, which is not the case with my situation.

**Workarounds**

Yes, I know about these workarounds:

- Ctrl + O
- Drag `.sql` files to SSMS

I am *not* looking for workarounds.

**My environment**

Even with the new SSMS 17.9.1 (build: 14.0.17289.0), I am still pointing to SQL Server 2016 (13.0.5233.0). Previously, I was using SSMS June 2016 (build: 13.0.15000.23) with the same SQL Server (13.0.5233.0).

Because of permission, I am not running any application as administrator.

---

SQL Server versions are listed [here](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/).

SQL Server Management Studio versions are listed [here](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2018/01/sql-server-management-studio-ssms.html).

Comment: Are you running SSMS as administrator?  If so, are you also running Explorer as administrator (or wherever you are double-clicking)?

Comment: @tgolisch No, nothing is being run as administrator.

Comment: I think this really belongs on SuperUser. This issue really is not related to SSMS specifically. VTC

Comment: FWIW, I have no such problem with my copy of SSMS 17.9.1 on W10, so this is not a universal and unfixable issue. (SQL Server versions are irrelevant; this is strictly an OS/application issue.)