# When opening .sql file from the P4V it starts in the new SQL Management Studio instance instead of opening in new tab

Tags: file, ssms, p4v

When opening .sql file from the P4V it starts in the new SQL Management Studio instance instead of opening in new tab.

Comment: Its a well described issue. The OP could not post an example as there is no code to post or example to give. Therefore the OP described the issue, using words, possibly not in their first language, very succinctly. Thanks for asking the question, it saved me a ton of pain. Please come back to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Issue has two items:

1. Windows explorer file associate should be correct configured ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726577/sql-management-studio-wont-open-scripts-on-double-click)).
2. The P4V has its own file-associate. It should be deleted:

Menu-->Edit-->Preferences-->File Editors and delete .sql associate.